# Why is FlickrAPI hanging after giving the results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, flickr

I am trying to scrape images from Flickr using the FlickrAPI. What is happening is that the command line just stays there and nothing happens after the image URLs have been scraped. It's something like the following:
[image]

Nothing happens after this screen, it stays here for a long time, somewhere in the range of 1200 seconds or more sometimes.

For scraping I used the following code:

```
def get_urls(search='honeybees on flowers', n=10, download=False):
    t = time.time()
    flickr = FlickrAPI(key, secret)
    license = ()  # https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/?method=flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo
    photos = flickr.walk(text=search,  # http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html
                         extras='url_o',
                         per_page=500,  # 1-500
                         license=license,
                         sort='relevance')

    if download:
        dir = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'images' + os.sep + search.replace(' ', '_') + os.sep  # save directory
        if not os.path.exists(dir):
            os.makedirs(dir)

    urls = []
    for i, photo in enumerate(photos):
        if i < n:
            try:
                # construct url https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html
                url = photo.get('url_o')  # original size
                if url is None:
                    url = 'https://farm%s.staticflickr.com/%s/%s_%s_b.jpg' % \
                          (photo.get('farm'), photo.get('server'), photo.get('id'), photo.get('secret'))  # large size

                download
                if download:
                    download_uri(url, dir)

                urls.append(url)
                print('%g/%g %s' % (i, n, url))
            except:
                print('%g/%g error...' % (i, n))

    # import pandas as pd
    # urls = pd.Series(urls)
    # urls.to_csv(search + "_urls.csv")
    print('Done. (%.1fs)' % (time.time() - t) + ('\nAll images saved to %s' % dir if download else ''))
```

This function is called as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--search', type=str, default='honeybees on flowers', help='flickr search term')
    parser.add_argument('--n', type=int, default=10, help='number of images')
    parser.add_argument('--download', action='store_true', help='download images')
    opt = parser.parse_args()

    get_urls(search=opt.search,  # search term
             n=opt.n,  # max number of images
             download=opt.download)  # download images
```

I tried going through the function code multiple times but I can't seem to understand why nothing happens after the scraping is done, as everything else is working fine.

Comment: you have `per_page=500` so maybe it still runs code for other images but you use `if i < n` to skip displaying any info - so it still run code for `490` images and you wait for end. You should rather use `break` to exit loop when `i >= n`. OR you should use `photos[:n]` to work only with `n` images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run it but I think all problem is that it gets information about 500 photos - because you have `per_page=500` - and it runs `for`-loop for all 500 photos and you have to wait for the end of `for`-loop.

You should use `break` to exit this loop after `n` images

```
    for i, photo in enumerate(photos):
        if i >= n:
           break
        else: 
            try:
               # ...code ...
```

Or simply you should use `photos[:n]` and then you don't have to check `i < n`

```
    for i, photo in enumerate(photos[:n]):
        try:
           # ...code ...
```

---

Eventually you should use `per_page=n`

---

**BTW:**

You can use `os.path.join` to create path

```
dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images', search.replace(' ', '_'))
```

If you use `exist_ok=True` in `makedirs()` then you don't have to check `if not os.path.exists(dir):`

```
if download:
   dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images', search.replace(' ', '_'))
   os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
```

If you use `enumerate(photos, 1)` then you get values `1,2,3,...` instead of `0,1,2,...`

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the error. I used the `if i >= n` part because using `photos[:n]` will cause a "generator is not subscritable" error. Thanks anyways for pointing out the error!

Comment: then you may need `list(photos)[:n]`